# Make wacom settings permanent

Tags: xorg, wacom, etc

How to make wacom tablet settings permanent?
I have these settings:

```
~ xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pad pad" button 1 "key PgDn"
~ xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos PT S 2 Pad pad" button 3 "key PgUp"
```

OS: ubuntu 16.04

If according to [this](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration#Profiles)  I make a shell script and make it run on startup. It will only work for the first time. As soon as I disconnect the tablet I will need to run the shell script again.
Are there any config file I can edit?
This what my X11 looks like:

```
/e/X11  pwd
/etc/X11
 /e/X11  ls
app-defaults/            rgb.txt             xorg.conf.10272016  xorg.conf.11242016  Xsession*
cursors/                 xinit/              xorg.conf.10292016  Xreset*             Xsession.d/
default-display-manager  xkb/                xorg.conf.10302016  Xreset.d/           Xsession.options
fonts/                   xorg.conf.10262016  xorg.conf.11232016  Xresources/         xsm/
 /e/X11 
```

Comment: Hi! Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better, cleaner solution involving xorg config files but I recently learned that this works to the same effect:

Append those two lines to the bottom of the ".profile" file in your "/home/" folder. It's a hidden file by default just so you are aware. This way, they will be run automatically every time you log in.